# Is it possible to create a Watchface in pebble js?

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

http://developer.getpebble.com/getting-started/watchface-tutorial/part1/ is in C. Is there a way to do the same thing in JS?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.  I think [pebble.js](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/pebblejs/) currently only supports applications, rather than watchfaces, as they run on the phone and don't have enough access to be able to update the UI in the way a watchface needs to.

Comment: [James Thorpe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/791010/james-thorpe) is correct here that you will not be able to create the watchface in pure pebble.js, but you would be able to interact with the watchface to create the display using pebble.js.

Comment: Can you explain your last comment about interacting with the watchface using pebble.js? Is there some example code?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can! You will just need to change the type of app in the appinfo.json:

- In CloudPebble, just go to your project *Settings* and change the AppKind to "Watchface".
  [image]
- If you are writing apps with the command line SDK you need to [fork pebble.js](https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs/) and edit the [appinfo.json file](https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs/blob/master/appinfo.json#L10) to set `"watchface": true` (see the [app metadata](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/app-structure/app-metadata) doc for reference).

A few things to note:

- Pebble.js apps actually run on the phone and remote control the Pebble. If you update the display too often (every second for example) it will cost a lot in battery life because the radio will be used a lot.
- To update the seconds automatically, without sending radio messages every time, you can use the ["TimeText" element](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/pebblejs/#timetext) in pebble.js.
- Just like all watchfaces your app will not receive button events if it is configured to be a Watchface. You can still use the accelerometer and tap events though.

Comment: Do you have a working version of the PebbleJS WatchFace? I changed the App Kind to Watchface but when I run it, it still runs as an app and not a watchface.

Comment: Can you contact us: devsupport@getpebble.com? Mention this thread and add a link to your project on cloudpebble. We will look into this. It should work ;)

Comment: I'm new to Pebble SDK(still waiting for my Pebble2 shipping), does that means I can't update watchface UI(build with JS) if Pebble & phone didn't connect ?

Answer (score 1):

Since SDK 4 you can program watchfaces using js 
https://developer.pebble.com/blog/2016/08/30/announcing-pebble-sdk4/

Answer (score 0):

You can build and interface to the watchface with **[pebble js](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/js-apps/pebblekit-js/)**, since a pebble js app project in pebble is [just a pebble C wrapped app](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/js-apps/pebble-js/).

> Pebble.js is built on top of the standard Pebble C SDK and PebbleKit
>   JS. It includes a C app that runs on the watch and interacts with the
>   phone for every user interaction. The Pebble.js library provides
>   objects and functions to build the UI and then remote-controls the C
>   app to display them.
>
> Note: PebbleKit Android and PebbleKit iOS cannot be used in
>   conjunction with PebbleKit JS. Remove any JavaScript files in the
>   Pebble project to ensure communication with Android and iOS companion
>   apps.

#### Warning: As of today (Feb 18, 2015) [Pebble.js](https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs) is still in Beta

Comment: Does it allow for creating watch _faces_ though, not just watch _apps_?

Comment: Oh, no, that would not be possible without the interface piece of the app already being a Watchface.  I understand what you mean now. I will edit my answer. :(

Comment: I really need to get around to trying some of this stuff... I've had a pebble for a year now, still haven't written a line of code for it - was sort of hoping your answer would be an easy way in :)

Comment: There is no way around the interface piece, but it is fun to create apps with it.  Good luck!